# How can I install python-dev without sudo?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, installation

I am trying to install python package (scikits.learn) on my user directory (on a ubuntu server for which I don't have sudo permission) but I am getting

```
error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

It may be because I don't have python-dev installed. But how can I install python-dev without sudo? OR is there any other easy way out for Python.h?

Comment: 1) What Linux distro? 2) The question is not *exactly* on topic here, it may get migrated somewhere else. 3) See [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/23734/is-there-any-way-to-get-apt-to-install-packages-to-my-home-directory) for some ideas.

Comment: 1. on ubuntu server

Answer (score 3):

You can compile your own python from the sources, and then install any modules what you want.
http://docs.python.org/devguide/

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is a little bit of necromancy (reviving old posts) but I faced the same issue and could not find an answer, so I'm sharing the one I found...

My solution:

I am working on an ubuntu 16.04 Desktop, with no sudo and only python 2.7 installed. I managed to setup a virtualevn without sudo (following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348869/how-to-install-virtualenv-without-using-sudo) and when trying to install jupyter I came across the missing "error: Python.h: No such file or directory".

My solution, not at all clean but at least confined to **virtualenv and virtual python folder** is:

1. create a test directory (package_download)
2. no-sudo@pc:~/package_download$ apt-get download libpython2.7-dev
3. no-sudo@pc:~/package_download$ apt-get download python-dev
4. no-sudo@pc:~/package_download$ dpkg -x libpython2.7-dev_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb .
5. no-sudo@pc:~/package_download$ dpkg -x python-dev_2.7.11-1_amd64.deb .

This will download the library and extract them in your package_download folder. Now comes the dirty part, since pip did not allow me to target this location, I added this files to where they belong, inside the virtualenv folder...

6. Merge "~/package_download/usr/bin" with the bin directory inside your **virtual python** installation folder (the one that you used to install virtualenv and create your enviroment) but do not replace any file.
7. Merge "~/package_download/usr/lib" with the lib directory inside your **virtual python** folder. No conflicts here.
8. Copy the contents of "~/package_download/usr/include/python2.7" to your include/python2.7/ folder, no conflicts here. This is actually the most dirty part, since we are modifying the install folder of the **virtual python** (this do not needs sudo, since is a no-sudo **virtual python**).
9. Copy the folder "~/package_download/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu" to your include/python2.7/ folder. Copying folders no problem here...

now run your virtual env:

10. no-sudo@pc:~/running_virtualenv$ source bin/activate
11. (running_virtualenv)no-sudo@pc:~/running_virtualenv$ pip install jupyter
12. enjoy...

If you found that your **include/python2.7/** is a symbolic link then you have mistaken the virtualenv folder with the virtual python folder. (Thanks @andrzej1_1 for finding this issue)

Comment: Is this an answer or a question? If a question, make new question (and explain why this one didn't help).

Comment: Sorry, the first part is confusing, it is an answer. I'll add the clarification.

Comment: Your solution does not work for me. In my case `~/virt_env/include/python2.7` is pointing to `/usr/lib/python2.7`, which cannot be modified by non-root user.

Comment: @andrzej1_1 , I'm not  sure why is that, maybe you installed virtualenv without "--no-site-packages" flag?  Anyway, you can try to replace that symbolic link with a folder. Mine only contains 3 symbolic links inside include/python2.7: "Imaging.h -> /usr/include/python2.7/Imaging.h", "ImDib.h -> /usr/include/python2.7/ImDib.h" and "ImPlatform.h -> /usr/include/python2.7/ImPlatform.h" .

Comment: @RamiroR.C. Yep, I didn't use that flag. I will try and let you know.

Comment: There is no need to use it: "Not having access to global site-packages is now the default behavior.". Replacing symlink with content of `/usr/include/python2.7` does not help.

Comment: @RamiroR.C. I prepared gist with commands: https://gist.github.com/koxu1996/c09330b195504d34088a1160f2d68e69 Could you test it?

Comment: @andrzej1_1 I found an error in my code, I confused some folders in my system, more specific, I confused the virtual_env folder with the virtual_python folder. I had installed virtualenv through virtual_python script (see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348869/how-to-install-virtualenv-without-using-sudo ). I will edit the answer and add the lines to install the virtual python.

Comment: @RamiroR.C. Now it's working :) I updated gist with correct commands.

Comment: @RamiroR.C. If I am using CentOS or i don't have apt-get utility to download package then how can i download python into this folder

Comment: @WaseemAli **apt-get** only downloads the package and **dpkg -x** extracts its package content.  **libpython2.7-dev_2.7.12-1ubuntu0~16.04.1_amd64.deb** is the specific name of the libpython2.7 package for ubuntu 16.04 64bits. You need to get the package that corresponds to your system (maybe using yum-downloadonly from an other PC?), but I have no experience with that system...

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to try this method for me, with a different package manager, since `yum` cannot download a package without installing -_-